# Manage database connection with Python singletons

Tags: python, singleton, database-connection, psycopg2

I have created my own module to manage objects in database. In order to limit the connections to the database, I design a dedicated class in a singleton way.

The construstor is invoked as expected but the destructor is never invoked so the database connection is never close.

```
class DBConnection:
    instance = None
    con = None

    def __new__(cls):
    if DBConnection.instance is None:
        DBConnection.instance = object.__new__(cls)
    return DBConnection.instance

    def __init__(self):
    if DBConnection.con is None:
        try:
            DBConnection.con = psycopg2.connect(database='...', user='...', password='...')
            print('Database connection opened.')
        except psycopg2.DatabaseError as db_error:
            print("Erreur :\n{0}".format(db_error))

    def __del__(self):
    if DBConnection.con is not None:
        DBConnection.close()
        print('Database connection closed.')
```

The first instance printed "Database connection opened." as expected. The second instance printed nothing as expected. The first instance deleted printed nothing as expected. The second instance deleted printed nothing but I was expected the message "Database connection closed".

I easily understand the reason: a reference still exists, but I don't know why. How can I delete all the references in order to close the database connection?

Regards,
Serge

Answer (score 0):

`DBConnection.instance` holds a reference to your singleton instance. A new call to `DBConnection()` would still return the existing value of `DBConnection.instance`. You will need to store a [`weakref`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html) for your singleton instance in `DBConnection.instance` if you don't want it to count towards the reference count of your instance.

Comment: Thank you @lanzz for your reply. According to you, how can I store weakref for my class instance? The only way I see is to create a first instance and then create weakref to the first one but I still can't close my database connection...

Comment: I could help you, if you post your attempts to use a `weakref`. The module docs provide plenty of examples of `weakref` usage. I can't guess why your instance is still not released without seeing your modified code.